# Argocd notifications for long running sync operations

Tags: argocd

I'm running Argocd 2.7.4 and I want to get an alert for sync operations that take longer than a few minutes. I tried using the example from the documentation (https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/notifications/triggers/#functions)

```
  when: time.Now().Sub(time.Parse(app.status.operationState.startedAt)).Minutes() >= 5
```

However, that only triggers after the operation has finished which is kinda useless for my usecase. Is it actually possible to create an alert like this with argocd directly or do I need to build it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is not natively supported, which means you would need to use a combination of Argo CD's API and a monitoring tool like [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/). The idea would be to expose Argo CD's metrics to Prometheus and then create an alert based on the duration of the sync operation.

Here is a high-level outline of the steps you can follow:

First, Expose Argo CD's [Application Controller Metrics](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/metrics/) to Prometheus by configuring the `argocd-metrics` service.

And set up Prometheus to scrape the metrics from Argo CD, using the [Prometheus configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/).

See for example "[Argo CD metrics with Prometheus operator and Datadog](https://medium.com/@riteshnanda09/argo-cd-metrics-with-prometheus-operator-and-datadog-ad13954c7024)" by [Ritesh Nanda](https://www.linkedin.com/in/riteshnanda) (Oct. 2022)

Then create a custom alert in Prometheus based on the duration of the sync operation.

That would involve querying the applications' status ([ApplicationService](https://cd.apps.argoproj.io/swagger-ui#tag/ApplicationService)): a GET request to the `/api/v1/applications/{applicationName}` endpoint will include information about the application's sync status in the `status.sync.status` field.

To expose the sync operation durations to Prometheus, you would need to [create a custom exporter](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/). This exporter would run the script to fetch the sync operation durations and expose them as a Prometheus metric.

```py
import requests
import time
from dateutil.parser import parse
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Gauge

# URL of the Argo CD API server
argo_cd_api_server = "http://<argocd-server>:<port>"

# Create a Gauge metric to track sync operation durations
SYNC_DURATION = Gauge('argocd_sync_duration_seconds', 'Duration of sync operations', ['application'])

def fetch_sync_durations():
    # Get a list of all applications
    response = requests.get(f"{argo_cd_api_server}/api/v1/applications")
    applications = response.json()["items"]

    for application in applications:
        # Get the status of the application
        response = requests.get(f"{argo_cd_api_server}/api/v1/applications/{application['metadata']['name']}")
        status = response.json()["status"]

        # If the application is currently syncing, calculate the duration of the sync operation
        if status["sync"]["status"] == "Syncing":
            started_at = parse(status["operationState"]["startedAt"])
            current_duration = time.time() - started_at.timestamp()
            SYNC_DURATION.labels(application=application['metadata']['name']).set(current_duration)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics
    start_http_server(8000)
    # Fetch sync operation durations every 60 seconds
    while True:
        fetch_sync_durations()
        time.sleep(60)
```

That would define a Gauge metric named `argocd_sync_duration_seconds`, created to track the duration of sync operations.
The `fetch_sync_durations` function fetches the sync operation durations and sets the value of the Gauge metric for each application.
The script then starts a HTTP server to expose the metrics and runs the fetch_sync_durations function every 60 seconds.

Finally, configure an alert manager to send notifications based on the alert. You can follow the [Prometheus Alertmanager documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/) to set up the alert manager and configure the notification channels (e.g., Slack, email, etc.).

A bit convoluted, but that would enable a custom alert for long-running sync operations in Argo CD.

---

> Can the existing `argocd_app_info` metric be used here?
> E.g `argocd_app_info{sync_status!="Synced"}` while also setting the `for` value in the Prometheus alert.

The [`argocd_app_info` metric](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/metrics/) provides various information about ArgoCD applications, including their sync status. But I do not think it would directly include the *duration* of the sync operation.

The idea to filter applications where `sync_status!="Synced"` is a good starting point to identify applications that are currently in the process of syncing or in a non-synced state.
The main limitation of using `argocd_app_info` for your use case is that it does not track how long an application has been in a particular sync state. The metric can tell you the current state but not the duration of that state.

The [`for` clause in Prometheus alerting rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) is used to specify a duration for which a condition must hold before firing an alert.
For instance, if you set a rule with `for: 5m`, Prometheus will fire the alert only if the condition is true continuously for 5 minutes.

However, in the case of `argocd_app_info`, since the metric does not include the duration of the sync status, the `for` clause would not apply to how long the app has been syncing. It would apply to the condition being true (e.g., the app being in a non-synced state) for that duration.

So, to achieve the desired alerting for long-running sync operations, you would still likely need to implement a custom solution to track the duration of each sync operation, as discussed in the original solution above. That custom solution would involve querying the ArgoCD API or using a custom exporter script that calculates the duration of the sync operations and exposes this data to Prometheus.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think having this alert would be useful to literally all argocd users.

Comment: @Baju I agree, that should be a native feature somehow.

Comment: Can the existing argocd_app_info metric be used here? E.g `argocd_app_info{sync_status!="Synced"}` while also setting the for value in the Prometheus alert.

Comment: @Mr_Tree I have edited the answer to address your comment.